# Column totals in Vim

Tags: vim, sum

Does anyone know how to sum all colums in a table in Vim without using AWK or SED but vimscript?

I want to select the columns which I want to sum and have the value below

like this:

```
2,50       € 2,50
25         € 2.200,40
0,30       € 0,309
100        € 1.400,3
23,50      € 23,5
--------------------
Sum col1   Sum col2
```

This is an example with 2 columns, but I often have more columns.
The problem I had with awk is that it cannot handle the decimals seperator "," and thousand seperator "."

Comment: actually, the plugin handles decimals correctly. Read the help on the SumCol command, which provides an example (see :h SumCol_CSV)

Comment: @Christian I have to create a CSV file from my 2 columns in the text isn't it? I can't make it work without creating such a file.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the specifics of your question but it's a similar problem to one I have from time to time, where I'm editing columns of numbers, and want to sum the columns without having to use some `awk` line and don't want to have to include a plugin. Instead I wrote a very light utility in Python, that compiles via Cython into a binary, that I can then use as a filter by highlighting rows and using a simple Vim command like `:!colsum`. You can vary the code to fit your use-case. Full instructions (not very long) in the repo: https://github.com/anilsg/colsum

Answer (score 3):

I'd recomend to take a look at [csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim) source, it has a `SumColumn` function IIRC in the ftplulgin.

Comment: I tried this plugin but it doesn't handle the decimals "," and it doesn't work with column selection (but it is a nice plugin for csv files).

Comment: I didn't said it solves your problem. But it might help to get you started. E.g. wrap the function around copy the marked visual column to a temporary buffer, replace every `,` to `.`, then call the function, and copy the result back.

Answer (score 2):

I need this enough that it needed to be easier.

Added the below to my `.vimrc` and can now:

- Visually select the column
- Yank it into the default register *(`y`)*
- `<Leader>s` in normal mode—*copies the summed result into the `*` register*
  *(`*` register may not be available with your vim build, but you could change it from `let @* = ...` to `let @" = ...`, or whatever register you want the result saved to)*.
- paste the result `p`, in normal mode.

```perl
function Sum()
    let @* = system("awk '{total+=$1}END{print total}'", @")
endfunction

function Sub()
    let @* = system("awk '{total-=$1}END{print total}'", @")
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>s :call Sum()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>x :call Sub()<CR>
```

---

**Update**

You did mention a pure Vim way, and I gave you an `awk` way

This also works, with a few more steps *(surely some shortcuts could be added)*

```
function Sum()
    let @a = substitute(trim(@"), "\<c-j>", "+", "g")                                                              
endfunction
```

- Visually select the column
- `:call Sum()`
- Move to where you want the value
- In insert mode: Cr=Cra ← *(Ctrl+r = Ctrl+r a)*